# Visual Studio SDK Determining if a Single Project is Up-to-date

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-sdk

I am currently developing a Visual Studio Extension. I need to find out the Up-To-Date status on each project in the current solution. So far the most useful thing I've found (I've done a LOT of searching through Microsoft's SDK docs) is...

```
IVsSolutionBuildManager3.AreProjectsUpToDate();
```

This is fine for determining the existence of a project that is not up to date but I cannot find a way to get this information at the project level. Is there a quick way to do this? Or will I have to do something more complicated like comparing input and output file creation times?